# Determining whether the ordinary differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin(xy)$ is linear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=sin(xy) .$$ Is this linear or nonlinear?

My approach:

Expanding $\sin(xy)$ which involves higher powers of $y$ so the equation is nonlinear.

Is this right? Otherwise, how to do it?

Comment: It's the right spirit, but it's not very rigorous to write "involves higher powers of $y$".

Comment: why ? what is wrong there i don't know

Comment: What does it mean to "involve higher powers of $y$"? Are you talking about a Taylor expansion? Anyway, what is your definition of linearity?

Comment: yes taylor expansion. Linearity means no power of dependent variable and its derivatives and also they are not multiplied together.

Comment: Well, $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin xy$ doesn't involve powers of the dependent variable or its derivatives, nor are they multiplied together, but the O.D.E. here is nonlinear. For that matter $\frac{dy}{dx} = (y^3)^{1 / 3}$ is linear, even though it involves powers of the depending variable. One can appeal to a Taylor expansion like you suggest, as what matters here is that the r.h.s. of the O.D.E. is linear in $y$, which it isn't. See my answer for a perhaps more straightforward approach.

Comment: i got what u say but i have one doubt what is the problem in taylor expansion?

Comment: One can use Taylor expansion, but (1) one needs to say more than "which involves higher powers of $y$..." to justify using it, and (2) this introduces a technical issue, namely that we have to restrict to analytic functions (in this case, our r.h.s. is analytic in $y$). But there are nonzero smooth functions $f$ whose Taylor series (in $y$) is the zero series, and for such functions the corresponding O.D.E. $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x, y)$ is still not linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right spirit, but it's not very rigorous to write "involves higher powers of $y$". To make this more precise, recall that by definition a first-order O.D.E. is linear if we can write it as
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = a(x) y(x) + b(x)$$
(for some nice function $a(x)$).

Now, if we regard the $x, y$ as independent variables and regard the r.h.s. as a function of $x$ and $y$, namely, $a(x) y + b(x)$, it is linear in $y$, and so differentiating twice gives $$\partial_y^2 (a(x) y + b(x)) = 0 ,$$ and so if an equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x, y(x))$ is linear, it must have the property that $(\partial_y^2 f)(x, y) = 0$; in fact, this condition is sufficient.

On the other hand, in our example, we have $f(x, y) = \sin xy,$ so $(\partial_y^2 f)(x, y) = -x^2 \sin xy$, which is not zero, and hence $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin x y$$ is *not* linear.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

A differential equation $y' = \ldots$ is linear if the RHS has the form $f(x)y' + g(x)y + h(x)$ with functions $f,g,h$ of $x$. Is this the case here?

Comment: no here nothing like that

Comment: Indeed, exactly. :o)